# JAVA checking if an array contains a value diffrent than the value given

Tags: java

I have a declaration of a ArrayList T

```
ArrayList<Integer> T = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And i have a while loop which should be active until the list will be composed of only -1 int's. Currently it looks like this:

```
 while(T.contains(!-1))
```

As you probably guessed it. It does not work properly since i can't use negation on a integer.

Comment: ***T.contains(!-1)***??? what does that suppose to mean?

Comment: the problem is that you are using "!" on the wrong place, the wile loop works with condition, and the condition you need it that "not contains", try putting the "!" before your condition

Comment: Yeah if i use negation on

    while(!T.contains(-1))

the loop will end after FIRST -1 int lands into T. But the loop has to end only if the ENTIRE list is made of -1's.

Comment: Voting to close as a typographical error

Comment: @melli-182 not sure that'll fix it, he wants to run the while loop until the list contains only `-1`s. and `contains()` won't help there.

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Stream#allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-).

```
while(!T.stream().allMatch(i -> i == -1)){ // note the ! operator to negate the result
       //do something              
}
```

This should keep looping until the list will be composed of only `-1` ints as you've suggested.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to fix my problems.

Answer (score 0):

> But the loop has to end only if the ENTIRE list is made of -1's.

You could use a `HashSet` that will remove all duplicated elements in the List.
 
if the `HashSet` object has a size of 1 (it means that the list contains only the same value) and if the first element of the list is `-1`, it means that the list contains only `-1` values.

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while (!(new HashSet<Integer>(integers).size() == 1 && integers.get(0).intValue() == -1)){
     ....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can stream the list:

```
List<Integer> myList = ...;
myList = myList.stream().filter(x -> x < 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repetitively check whether there are elements that are not -1 in the list, you can do it as below for efficiency:

1. Count the number of elements that are not -1 and store this value in `n`
2. `while (n > 0) { do stuff; and decrease n if the value of an element becomes -1 }`